# add a new button to window dynamically

Tags: c#

Am totally new to MVVM Design,I think u can solve my problem

Now , Am doing that Appl... In that i have a button in a window now i want that every time wen i click on that button it has to add a new button to my window dynamically

i think u can help me ...

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You're probably lacking a call to Controls.Add().  Just create a button and add it to the parent control's 'Controls' collection.